# List of character encoding conversions required : windows-1252 to UTF-8

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, windows-1252

I have an SQL Server database full of badly-encoded characters. The issue was the ETL was written in Java with the wrong default encoding, and was therefore directly loading the badly-encoded characters. The database is literally holding the characters Ã¶ instead of ö

I've fixed the issue with the ETL, now I would like to fix the existing data. I know I can use REPLACE() to replace the characters, but my issue is that I do not have a definitive list of characters and what they're "supposed" to be.

I have scoured the internet for some sort of definitive list but I cannot find one. I just need a big list of this:

Ã¶ > ö

Ã© > é

etc

EDIT: I first thought the "bad" encoding was ISO 8859-15, actually I just checked the previous default charset and it is windows-1252. I have updated the title of the post.

Comment: As a slightly different approach, which I have used in the past, you can write a small app to pull the data out using the incorrect encoding, so that now you have the string you want in your app, then write it back this time using the correct encoding.

Comment: Encode the windows-1252 characters to UTF-8 and read it again (so decoding) as windows-1252 (without passing to UTF-8). You may find the characters in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 [and BTW the page is in UTF-8, so you may skip the first step]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a big list.  UTF-8 encodes all of Unicode in one to four bytes per Unicode code point.  There are 1,114,111 Unicode code points (1,112,064 if UTF-16 surrogates are discounted).

It is easier to read the strings using Windows-1252, encode them to bytes using Windows-1252, decode them with UTF-8.  Example in Python since its what I have available to demo:

```
>>> s = 'Ã¶Ã©'
>>> s.encode('Windows-1252').decode('UTF-8')
'öé'
```

Note though, that Windows-1252 is lossy.  Some bytes used in UTF-8 don't have a definition in Windows-1252, so its possible that when written to your database they were dropped.  It's also possible that `ISO-8859-1` was used (aka `latin1`) which is close to Windows-1252 but all bytes are defined.